# How to power off an Android device?

Tags: android

How could I power off an android device via java code?
Is it even possible? Do I need special permissions to do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no API in the Android SDK to allow user apps to do this.

The closest you could perhaps try would be [`PowerManager.goToSleep()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/PowerManager.html#goToSleep%28long%29).

Comment: I know there is this one app called "Power off" but i cant find the source code for that one :(

Comment: I think you'd need permission `DEVICE_POWER` which is system only.

Comment: There are apps on the Market that use internal, non-public APIs, or require your phone to be rooted. It's not an advisable approach.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, It is possible but you need a `Rooted` device with `Superuser` Access. Try using the following code:

```
try {
    Process proc = Runtime.getRuntime()
                    .exec(new String[]{ "su", "-c", "reboot -p" });
    proc.waitFor();
} catch (Exception ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
```

If you plan on doing this without `Root Privileges`, forget it. The only way to do that is to use `PowerManager` but that won't work unless your app is signed with the `System Firmware Key`.

*[via [Programmatically switching off Android phone](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12430612/1533054)]*