# How to poweroff android mobile

Tags: android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to power off an Android device?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2038151/how-to-power-off-an-android-device)

I have a requirement to implement power-off functionality on android. I am unable to get that. Is there anything I can call then my mobile will power-off. How do I write code to power-off?

Thanks

Comment: reboot is possible, but no idea about shutting it down. For reboot, check this link: [Power Manager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/PowerManager.html)

Comment: instruct the user to remove battery =/  lol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found there is no API in the Android SDK to allow user apps to do this.
Force the device to go to sleep using `PowerManager.goToSleep()`

Answer (score 1):

Sorry,  there is no way to do it !

Comment: please try to be more descriptive in your answers and leave more then one sentence. Why is it not possible?